# Registering a global error handler in AngularJS fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to create a global HTTP error handler to catch problems with authentication or availability of the backend. My code looks like the following:

```
var foo= angular.module('foo',[]);

foo.factory('HttpErrorInterceptor',function($q){
    return {
        'response': function(response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            console.log(rejection);
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});

foo.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpErrorInterceptor');
    //...
})
```

When I try to run this (Other code and dependencies are stripped for this question) I get the following exception:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module foo due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $httpProvider due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module '$httpProvider' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/nomod?p0=%24httpProvider
minErr/<@http://localhost/js/angular.js:68:12
module/<@http://localhost/js/angular.js:2034:17
ensure@http://localhost/js/angular.js:1958:38
module@http://localhost/js/angular.js:2032:14
loadModules/<@http://localhost/js/angular.js:4524:22
forEach@http://localhost/js/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@http://localhost/js/angular.js:4508:5
loadModules/<@http://localhost/js/angular.js:4525:40
forEach@http://localhost/js/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@http://localhost/js/angular.js:45
```

As you can see I'm using AngularJS 1.5.2.

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/LvhRC/90/) from your exact code. it works just fine.

Comment: What the heck... After I unsuccessfully tried the answers and changed my code back to the original version it's working for me too. Maybe there was something wrong with caching... (I swear I already checked this pitfall) I guess I will delete this question.  But thank you for your effort and I apologize for the noise.

Comment: Haha no worries. Happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("HttpErrorInterceptor");
}]);
```

Try this,hope it will work